# Pip extra index URL not working in alpine Docker images

Tags: python, docker, pip, alpine-linux

I have a Dockerfile with the following contents:

```
FROM python:3.9-alpine3.15
COPY my-project/ ./my-project/
COPY setup.py .
RUN pip install -e "." --extra-index-url "<extra-index-URL>"
```

I have hosted `my-package` in a private registry, but I get the following error from the `pip install` command:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement my-package>=1.5.0 (from my-project) (from versions: 0.0.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for my-package>=1.5.0
```

Version 0.0.1 is published to the official PyPI index, whereas higher versions are published to the private registry. The command succeeds locally on my Mac, as well as when I use the `python:3.9-bullseye` Docker image, so there's no issue with the registry itself. Apparently there is something preventing `alpine` to correctly use the private registry.

Since I want a more lightweight image, is there a way to make the command work with `alpine`?

Tried with Docker versions 20.10.11 on Mac and 20.10.17 on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Python often has issues with Alpine Linux. If I understood correctly, Alpine Linux uses a different C standard library than most other Linux distributions. So if you have a Python library with C extensions that you distribute as wheel (C extension is already compiled), then it needs to be compiled for Alpine Linux specifically as well. Wheels are not necessarily compatible with Alpine Linux. -- https://pythonspeed.com/articles/alpine-docker-python/

Comment: `pip install -vvv ...` will give you more info about the wheels `pip` finds on each index and why each possible installation candidate was discarded. Most probably it's the wrong wheel tag (not a `musllinux1`), as @sinoroc suggested in his comment, and there is no sdist uploaded to build the wheel locally from. If you encounter another issue, paste the verbose log to the question.